# Design architecture to handle links on view side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, architecture

In application, we have lots of if conditions on view side. 
Like which link should appear to specific user and which link should not.

I want to create a architecture which shows specific link to specific user but without writing any if condition on view side.

I am thinking to store all the links into the database and on the basis of roles links directly will come on view.

Looking for better ways to handle this scenario or better solution to solve out this problem.

What database design should be to handle this type of scenario ? How to design a architecture to handle it ?

Comment: Won't you still end up with lots of conditionals in your views do handle formatting and display issues when these links are there or not? Or are you talking about a straight list of links?

Comment: Can you give an example of your links? Is it just for a menu or do you handle create (role a), delete (role b) etc. permissions, too?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I missed something you're describing the role of `helpers` in Rails: extracting logic from views.

Comment: @aobeadiving I don't want to write any if condition on helper or view. From database I want to decide link should appear or not without writing any if condition on view side. Want design a architecture something like that way.

Comment: You need something to tie together which links appear for which set of users and then implement something like roles and perhaps pass around a hidden URL param.